# How to delete comment after publishing review?

Tags: review-board

After I add comment in View Diff window on Reviewboard, I can delete it before publishing (there is delete button in window when I click on comment in source code). When I publish changes and then I realize that comment was not clever then I would like to remove it. However there is no delete button anymore. How can be comment deleted after publishing it?

Comment: I just wrote something regrettable on my companies reviewboard instance and I'd like to delete it. If someone can answer this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for this issue a lot but i cannot find any way to delete a comment, although i can find a wiki to delete a review request but i think this feature is not supported up to review board version 2.0.1

For more information you can visit the reviewboard issue list and search for such a bug/feature 
<s>https://code.google.com/p/reviewboard/issues/list</s> (Project issue tracking moved to another site)
https://hellosplat.com/s/beanbag/tickets/